# Using MS Access 2000 VBA to send a Direct Message via the Twitter API

Tags: ms-access, vba, twitter

I am trying to send a direct message via the Twitter API from Access 2000 VBA.  I can post a status update to my Twitter account with the following code:

tUsername = "TwitterUser"
   tPassword = "theirpassword"
   tStatus = "some sample text"

xml.Open "POST", "http://" & tUsername & ":" & tPassword & "@twitter.com/statuses/update.xml?status=" & tStatus, False

This works fine, but when I try to follow the DM syntax, I get an "invalid request" -- something about the syntax where I have to specify the "-d" and the username I am not getting

The API help page from Twitter is here:
http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-direct_messages%C2%A0new

Thanks!

Comment: Overview of this command and syntax is here:  http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-direct_messages%C2%A0new

From the comments re the "curl" link below it does appear this is difficult, but I assume still doable?

Answer (score 0):

After clicking the ["cURL" link](http://www.sakana.fr/blog/2007/03/18/scripting-twitter-with-curl/), it seems there's more to it than just putting in the '-d' parameter.